# Try to inflate a custom viewpage android

Tags: android, viewpage

I have extend Viewpage class but the problem is I always get  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pindak.sarito/com.pindak.sarito.ui.ws.MagazineReaderActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.pindak.sarito.util.HackyViewPager. When trying to inflate it.

this is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.pindak.sarito.util.HackyViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/magazinepager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

this is the some of the code of my onCreate in activity

```
HackyViewPager pager = (HackyViewPager) findViewById(R.id.magazinepager);
```

and In com.pindak.sarito.util I have HackyViewPager.java

```
package com.pindak.sarito.util;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class HackyViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public HackyViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        try {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Any Ideas Why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried adding constructors that match both super constructiors?

```
public HackyViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public HackyViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```